# iOS - is there an SDK that can convert HTML5 webapps to native?

Tags: ios, html, native

I am working on an HTML5 webapp for computers, and I was thinking of making a mobile version.

Is there an SDK that can take HTML5/JS/CSS and convert it to a native iOS app I can upload on iTunesConnect?

The main thing that needs to work is the HTML5 Canvas... I haven't had any luck searching on Google.

Answer (score 5):

you don't need Phonegap or any other framework, load a web view control and load html files in folder using;

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                     ofType:@"html" 
                                                inDirectory:@"/htdocs" ];

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                              error:nil];

[webView loadHTMLString:html 
                baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/htdocs/", 
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]]];
```

Comment: Awesome... This worked, except on the iphone/ipad itself, it does not read sub-folders. Even if you put them in sub-folders in Xcode, your code has to assume there are no subfolders, so in the code above you make two changes:
(1) inDirectory:@""
(2) stringWithFormat:@"%@"

Answer (score 3):

http://trigger.io/ might help you.

> You write your HTML5 code using the Forge JavaScript API which gives you access to native features such as the camera and contacts API.
>
> Our cloud build service does the rest to create your native apps for iPhone, iPad, Android and Windows Phone.

Disclaimer: not associated with trigger.io in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at ludei.com they make it really easy. Just upload your .zip containing html and resources and it comes back as an .ipa

Really good work from them.

PS its free

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).  It's not a silver bullet but it does generally take HTML, CSS and JS and package it up to run on a mobile device with promises of cross-platform functionality.

We ran into a couple of cross platform compatibility issues with the Media object, but it should work with basic things like .

It basically just uses the phone's built-in webkit engine to execute your code, so if iOs supports it, it should technically work for you.

If you are developing on a mac then it's fairly straightforward.  There are plenty of "getting started" tutorials for phonegap / mac.  But if you're developing for iOs on a PC that's a whole 'nother story.

Either way, even to just test on a real iOs device, you will need an apple developer account, a provisioning profile and a developer key registered with apple.  If you are on a Mac you can use these to run the app via Xcode directly.

But if you are on a PC you will need to use Phonegap Build (a cloud-based service for building apps cross-platform).  From there you can download a compiled binary that can be installed via iTunes.

Hope this helps!